# How do you execute the "ctrl" + "t" shortcut in a chrome browser using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use shortcuts on the open browser using Selenium but nothing happends. I have tried a
few different methods below:

```
# Initialize the Chrome web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the first URL in the first tab
driver.get(url1)

# Open a new tab and switch to it
driver.execute_script("window.open('', '_blank');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

# Open the second URL in the second tab
driver.get(url2)
```

attempt one:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

attempt two:

```
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

attempt three:

```
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('1').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the reference [page](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/), the older code of `body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')` doesn't seem to work anymore.

But going through their page, the below code to add a new tab works for me:

```
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
```

And if you want to switch to different tabs:

```
tab_number = 0
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[tab_number])
```

Comment: Tried this method but still no luck. Running Windows and can open the URLs in two tabs but can't use the shortcut to navigate back to the first tab

Comment: @thomaskayll Edited after upgrading my selenium drivers, check if this works for you